Refresh graphql is not working in LWC
I have below wire method in LWC which is executing a graph query.
@wire(graphql, {
        query: mygraphquery
    })
    graphqlQueryResult(result) {
        this.graphedData = result
        const { data, errors } = result
        if (data) {
            console.log('data ', JSON.stringify(data))
            

        } else if (errors) {
            utility.logError(errors)
        }
    }

The above method gives the data and I manipulate it from the UI and update the data.
on click of save button I am calling below method
 await updateRecord({ fields }) // this updates the data returned by graph ql
await refreshGraphQL(this.graphedData ) // it is not refreshing the data

But this refreshGraphQL does not reexecute the wire method, it doesn't refresh the cached data if I close my modal popup and reopen again wire method returns stale data it does not provide the updated data can any one please help why refreshGraphQL is not working and why my graph ql is still giving stale data.
Can anyone please help, I have wasted good amount of time searhcing for this solution.

So, I'm having this issue too, but only in Local Dev (Winter '25 lightning dev plugin beta). I initially thought it was just generally not working, but then I deployed my source because I had a hunch... and lo and behold it works when running from my dev org instead of the lightning dev plugin. My observation is that the graphql query successfully returns from the server (as seen in the network tab of browser Dev tools) but the decorated function is never called. I'm trying to work out if I've missed something obscure or whether the local server is breaking things. What was your experience: we

Ran into the same issue, use metaschema-directives
